# CSS only works sometimes on dynamic image rendering in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I am building a recommender system for clothing and for that I am currently implementing a front-end with React. This front end is a chat in which the user can send text messages or upload an image. I dynamically render the messages from the bot (back-end) and the user (front-end). My problem is that the image behaves in an unpredictable way and first gets positioned correctly under the last message but every new messages just "ignores" the image and gets displayed wrong.

This is (part of) the react rendering output:

```
<div className="body">
                {/* Go through the array and display every message either as user or as bot message */}
                {messages.map((message, index) => {
                    if (message[2] === "bot") {
                        if (message[3] === "image") {
                            return (
                                <img
                                    src={message[0]}
                                    key={index}
                                    className="image botImage"
                                    alt="imageDisplayError"
                                ></img>
                            );
                        }
                        return (
                            <p className="message botMessage" key={index}>
                                {message[0]}
                            </p>
                        );
                    } else {
                        if (message[3] === "image") {
                            return (
                                <img
                                    src={message[0]}
                                    key={index}
                                    className="image usrImage"
                                    alt="imageDisplayError"
                                ></img>
                            );
                        } else {
                            return (
                                <p className="message usrMessage" key={index}>
                                    {message[0]}
                                </p>
                            );
                        }
                    }
                })}
            </div>
```

This is the relevant CSS code:

```css
.message {
    padding: 10px;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    /* Breaks messages into multiple lines */
    max-width: 350px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    hyphens: auto;
}

.botMessage {
    background-color: #037d7a;
    color: white;
}

.usrMessage {
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #07a7a4;
}

.image {
    /* padding-top: 15px; */
    max-width: 350px;
    max-height: 250px;
    /* margin-bottom: 15px; */
}

.usrImage {
    float: right;
}
```

[This is the output (I have the inspector open so you can see the bounding boxes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWG9J.png)

As you can see the image renders correctly under the initial message but every new messages just ignores the bounding box.

I would be grateful for ideas on how to fix this :)

I have already tried different CSS tricks with paddings and margins and so on as well as enclosing every element in a wrapper div so that an image and a text message get handled the same way.

Comment: can you please describe a **messages** Array format.

Comment: Sure (but I am not sure how that matters in this context, because it appears to be a formatting issue, or so I think). A message consists of the message content, the time it was sent, the sender („bot“ or „user“) and the type („text“ or „image“). Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am trying to recreate this thing in my local computer but I don't have any kind of mock-data according to you situation that is why i'm asking for and **Messages** array format (JSON). so with the help of it i can provide you a better solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. 
Let me know if you need any further information. If necessary I can also upload the whole code somewhere.

Comment: here is the basic structure -> [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-nobel-qsqy8v?file=/src/App.js) maybe this will work for you.

Comment:  No Problem brother. let me know how can i help you further. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was posted by Nirav.
This CSS seems to do the trick:

```css
.message {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.botMessage {
  background-color: #037d7a;
  color: white;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 250px;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.usrMessage {
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #07a7a4;
  color: white;
}

.usrImage {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```